# Relationship loading in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Just met a problem with relationships loading. The problem is when I'm trying to access to any relationship and it's null. I have generic repository and is there any way to enable eager loading in it, not in the entity configuration? Tried lazy loading but it isn't necessary as for me.

Comment: "I have generic repository" - **don't use the generic-repository anti-pattern with EF**. Your `DbContext` subclass and `DbSet<T>` types _already are your repository_. You're compromising the design of your application for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

When using Eager loading you can use the `Include` method to specify related data to be included in query results.

So, let's take a context of books that have many authors related to them. The books that are returned in the results will have their authors property populated with the related books.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
   var books = context.Books
      .Include(book => book.Authors)
      .ToList();
 }
```

More about eager loading of related data - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: In entity configuration... But, how can I do it in repository to load it dynamically?